# How to send Korean characters in URL?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to send some Korean values from page1.html  on page sumbit to page2.html. But the Korean fonts are getting encoded. Can any one help me with it. I have this meta tag in both the screens.

window.location.href = "page2.html?value='풍경' these Korean character are getting encoded in few mobile devices.

for this page the values is encode as

page2.html?value= %EC%82%EB%AC%BC

Comment: Please post what url you expect in this case. Handling of non-encoded Urls is not defined by most browsers/server....

Comment: I have send you the encoded script.. also actually i am working mobile web pages in few phones its getting encoded but for the latest phones it working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Korean characters (and any other non-URL-safe characters) are %-encoded for the transaction. However, when received by the server and put into (for instance) PHP's `$_GET` array, they are decoded automatically so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: What i have is simple HTML pages.. There is no server i am including. Only HTML and javascript, navigating through pages.

Comment: @Ranjithkumar why don't you just switch to PHP then? It seems like your URLs are in a format that utilizes `$_GET` variables anyways (specifically the `?value= %EC%82%EB%AC%BC` would be passed via php as `$_GET[value]`). Is there something that requires you to use only basic HTML and javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not completely clear on what you actually asking, but if you correctly construct Url it should be much easier to reason on what should/should not be happening:

```
// to construct correctly encoded Url:
var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent("'풍경'");
window.location.href = "page2.html?value=" + encodedValue; 

// to decode back from query parameter (if needed)
var decoded = decodeURIComponent(encodedValue);
```

Check out [Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript) for guidance on encoding Urls with JavaScript.