# HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect is removing Korean characters from URL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redirect, urlencode

I am trying to redirect to url which has a set of Korean characters at the end in query parameters.
Something like this - [https://somedomain.com?confirmationNumber=ABVLR0&bookingLastName=정숙](https://somedomain.com?confirmationNumber=ABVLR0&bookingLastName=%EC%A0%95%EC%88%99) , but when I redirect to browser using HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect the Korean characters are committed from browser.

I tried encoding and then decoding the url in utf-8 and utf-16 like this

```
    var url = URLEncoder.encode("https://somedomain.com?confirmationNumber=ABVLR0&bookingLastName=정숙", "UTF-8")

        response.sendRedirect(URLDecoder.decode(url,"UTF-8"))
```

but there was no success.
Please suggest what can I DO?

Answer (score 0):

This question covers some info about sending Korean characters and may be helpful:
[How to send Korean characters in URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906926/how-to-send-korean-characters-in-url)

One of the answers suggests using this syntax encodeURIComponent("'풍경'");

Therefore:

```
var url = encodeURIComponent("'https://somedomain.com?confirmationNumber=ABVLR0&bookingLastName=정숙'")

    response.sendRedirect(decodeURIComponent(url))
```

Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Kindly summarize contents from the link to keep contents available on SO

Comment: @artfulbeest Sorry, will do.

Comment: encodeURIComponent's equivalent in Kotlin is URLEncoder , I tried that as shown in code but no success. Problem is address bar of browser is omitting Korean characters.